# JSON response is not retaining the data except first record in the list returned from backend

Tags: json, rest

Returning a JSON response (list of objects) from spring controller to angularJS UI and when the list is displayed, it does not retain the child elements of second records onwards. See below JSON response- Object DTO has an arraylist in it which is getting populated fine when i checked in spring controller before returning ResponseEntity. but second records onward, see the flatCycles which is an ArrayList.

```
[
    {
        
        "block": "",
        "flat": "",
        "flatCycles": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "cycleIdentifier": "",
                "cycleDescription": ""
                
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "cycleIdentifier": "",
                "cycleDescription": ""
                
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "cycleIdentifier": "",
                "cycleDescription": ""
                
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        
        "block": "",
        "flat": "",
        "flatCycles": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    }       
]
```

Please suggest what an be possible root cause and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so found the answer after doing a lot of mind busting.

Issue was the fact that the flatCycles ArrayList in all the records were same, i.e. had same ID attribute and hence it can render only first one, after that it was not able to render. I made a DTO and removed the ID attribute from there and now all are populating fine.